# IE 8 specifying background-color changes element behavior

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

I have an absolutely positioned div on which I am trying to trigger mouseenter and mouseleave events. In IE8/7 with the background-color of the div left unspecified (so that it defaults to transparent), the mouseenter/leave events are not firing when the cursor crosses the div's boundary, only somewhere in the middle of the div and when the cursor is over any text within the div.

When I attempt to debug the problem by adding a background color to the div (e.g. background-color: green), the problem magically goes away. The div's box model is honored perfectly and mouseenter/leave fire as when expected. It's only when the div's background color is left unspecified (or even explicitly set to transparent) that it doesn't behave correctly.

Any ideas? Googling for this IE bug/quirk is coming up with nothing.

Comment: It's a bug in IE I've already met in the past. If an element is 100% transparent then IE doesn't consider it for mouse events.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mouseenter and mouseleave are not registering until the cursor hits something visible.  This is not correct behavior, but this is Explorer we're dealing with.

Two possible solutions:

1. <s>Put a thin border on the DIV, one that matches whatever is behind it and won't be noticed.</s>  *(This doesn't work; see the comments.)*
2. Track mousemove events and have your code determine when the mouse has entered the area of interest.
3. *(Added; see the comments.)*  Make your background a tiled transparent 1x1 image.

Both solutions are pretty much yuck, unfortunately.

**Edit:** Question:  Do mouseover and mouseout show the same weird behavior?

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Yes, mouseover/mouseout show the same behavior. Adding a border doesn't fix it either (even a clearly visible border). After the cursor passes over the border and towards the middle of the div, mouseleave fires again.

Comment: You mean to say the mouseleave fires any time you hit transparency *within* the element?  Wow, that's really broken.  What about tiling a 1x1 transparent image as a background, does that also break?  I know, it's getting more and more yucky.

Comment: You, my friend, nailed it. Transparent image background did it. I'll give you a chance to edit your answer so it's not buried in the comments before doing so myself. (To answer your first question, yes, mouseleave was firing within the element)

Answer (score 0):

To add to this:  onclick fires as well when using Solution 3, in the answer above.  It's overall a nice workaround for grabbing clicks on transparent elements over non-transparent ones in IE.